# The Music Bot is playing the Music but No One is able to hear

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const { getVoiceConnection } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const { createAudioPlayer} = require('@discordjs/voice');
const{createAudioResource} = require('@discordjs/voice');
const{NoSubscriberBehavior } = require('@discordjs/voice');
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'Joins and plays a video from youtube',
    execute: async (client, msg, arg, Discord) => {
        const voiceChannel = msg.member.voice.channel;

        if (!voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(msg.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return msg.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return msg.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!arg.length) return msg.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');

        // const validURL = (str) =>{
        //     var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
        //         return false;
        //     } else {
        //         return true;
        //     }
        // }

        // if(validURL(arg[0])){

        //     const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();
        //     const stream  = ytdl(arg[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});

        //     connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
        //     .on('finish', () =>{
        //         voiceChannel.leave();
        //         msg.channel.send('leaving channel');
        //     });

        //     await msg.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***Your Link!***`)

        //     return
        // }


        const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: voiceChannel.id,
            guildId: voiceChannel.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: msg.channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
        });

        const connection1 = getVoiceConnection(voiceChannel.guild.id);

        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;

        }
        const keywords = await arg.join(' ')
        const video = await videoFinder(keywords);

        if (video) {
            const stream = ytdl(video.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
            

         


            
           
            const subscription = connection1.subscribe(stream,{seek:0,volume:1});

           




            await msg.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***${video.title}***`)
        }
        else{
            msg.reply('No Results Found')
        }
        
    }
}
```

*Now the problem is that the message comes that it is playing the audio but no one is able to hear it*
I think probably it is due to the new **Discord.js v13**
i dont get any errors but can someone help me

Also in v12 it worked properly i had to change my code due to the new v13
i didnt get any help from documentation but now i am hoping from Stack

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: However the music is playing, but it's not broadcasting to the voice channel. According to the [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/voice/audio-resources.html#creation) you need a `Player` as well. You have included `createAudioResource` but never used it, you need that one to prepare an audio stream.

Comment: I made some changes to the code but still doesnt work 
you can refer to this link https://srcb.in/6OzLvz4IGp

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, however this seemed to fix it.
In your `index.js` file, make sure you are using the `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent while defining you client. Once I added it the audio worked perfectly fine.

```
const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES],
});
```

It's something I didn't even consider until I came across a completely unrelated error. Hopefully it helps!